# How to validate Django formfield when external data is required?

Tags: django, forms, validation

I want to create a custom FormField to use in my application and write appropriate validations against it as suggested at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/validation/#form-field-default-cleaning. In my case, its a list of SMS recipients.

However, part of the validation process requires me to verify that the nominated list of recipients are indeed recipients stored in the current user's address book. In particular, I need to reject any recipients that do not belong to the user.

How can I get access to a value (like the current user) that is stored in the request when performing the validation? Alternatively, is there any way I can pass this value in at the point of validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of validation should be performed in your view, but if you still want do it in form, then below, I think, what you wanted:

```
class SomeView(FormView):
    form_class = SomeForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(SomeView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({
            'extra_param': self.some_param
        })

        return kwargs

class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Human
        fields = ['name']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.extra_param = kwargs.pop('excluded_pk')  # you should pop it from kwargs before parent init call

        super(SomeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_name(self):
        name = self.cleaned_data['name']

        if name != self.extra_param:  # since extra_param is object variable you can use it here
            raise forms.ValidationError('tadaam!')

        return name
```

Comment: Thanks @madzhon. That was exactly the solution I was looking for!

I needed this validation in the form because the form is used on more than one page and the form doesn't map to a simple model.